# VS2010 form startup object list doesn't populate with form names

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

The plans on the project I am working on have changed now they ask for a main menu. Normally that is not a problem I just go to startup list. My startup object list does not contain any of the forms. Here is a screen shot. All the sites I have referenced stated that you can change it in a program.cs file, I don't have a file named. Any suggestions?
[image]

Comment: That's a VB.NET option, clearly you are using C# here.  Which starts at Program.Main()

Comment: @HansPassant The plant notification form did. I have fixed it now my program.cs file was moved in the solution explorer when I switched it from vs2012 to vs2010. Thanks though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Startup Object isn't a Form - it's which `Main` routine you want to use as your program's entry point.

You have one listed - `LabelManagement_2010_Program` has a compatible `Main` routine.  That method is the one you would need to edit in order to change the form that's opened on startup.

Comment: if that is not the form name. Then, where we could see the lists of those names? I thought it was form's name.